# parsing output from command call

Tags: python, string, subprocess, stdout, popen

So I'm trying to execute a shell command from python and then either store it in an array or directly parse the piped shell command.

I am piping the shell data via the subprocess command and verified the output using print statement and it worked just fine.

```
a = subprocess.Popen('filepath/command', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
b = a.stdout.read()
print(b)
```

Now, I am trying to parse out data out of an unknown amount of rows and 6 columns.  Since b should be one long string, I tried to parse the string and store the salient characters into another array to be used however I want to analyze the data.

```
i = 0
a = subprocess.Popen('filepath/command', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
b = a.stdout.read()
for line in b.split("\n\n"): #to scan each row with a blank line separating each row
    salient_Chars[i, 0] = line.split(" ")[3] #stores the third set of characters and stops at the next blank space
    salient_Chars2[i, 0] = line.split(" ")[4] #stores the fourth set of characters and stops at the next blank space
    i = i + 1
```

I get an error [TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'].  I searched this error and it means that I stored bytes and not a string using the Popen which I am not sure why since I verified it was a string with the print command.  I tried using check_output after searching for how to pipe shell commands into a string.

```
from subprocess import check_output
a = check_output('file/path/command')
```

This gives me a permission error so I would like to use Popen command if possible.

How do I get the piped shell command into a string and then how do I properly parse through a string that is divided into rows and columns with spaces in between columns and blank lines in between rows?

Comment: _since I verified it was a string with the print command_ Well that's not a way of verifying its a string... And obviously it _is not_ a string type object, otherwise that error wouldn't raise.

Comment: you can't split `bytes` on a `str`, use `b.split(b'\n\n')` and `line.split(b' ')`

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string

Comment: If you provide me the expected output I may help you out with the second part of your question

Comment: The expected output is just like your quoted answer for command_stdout.  -rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1.  Imagine that this line can be an unknown amount of rows and 6 columns.  Each line is separated by a blank line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Aaron Maenpaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2603/aaron-maenpaa)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/4396006):

> You need to decode the bytes object to produce a string:
>
> ```
> >>> b"abcde"
> b'abcde'
>
> # utf-8 is used here because it is a very common encoding, but you
> # need to use the encoding your data is actually in.
> >>> b"abcde".decode("utf-8") 
> 'abcde'
> ```

Therefore your code would look like:

```
i = 0
a = subprocess.Popen('filepath/command', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
b = a.stdout.read().decode("utf-8") # note the decode method
for line in b.split("\n\n"): #to scan each row with a blank line separating each row
    salient_Chars[i, 0] = line.split(" ")[3] #stores the third set of characters and stops at the next blank space
    salient_Chars2[i, 0] = line.split(" ")[4] #stores the fourth set of characters and stops at the next blank space
    i = i + 1
```

By the way, I don't really understand your parsing code, that will give you a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple` since you are passing a tuple to the list index in `salient_Chars` (assuming it is a list).

### Edit

Note that calling the `print` built-in method is *not* a way of checking whether the arguments passed are a plain string-type object. From the OP from the quoted answer:

> The communicate() method returns an array of bytes:
>
> ```
> >>> command_stdout
> b'total 0\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file2\n'
> ```
>
> However, I'd like to work with the output as a normal Python string.
>   So that I could print it like this:
>
> ```
> >>> print(command_stdout)
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file1
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 0 Mar  3 07:03 file2
> ```